# MYSQL Hit Counter

Tags: php, sql

So I'm trying to make a hit counter unique to each username.

I'm trying to make it so that if the username isn't in the database, it inserts the username into a field called username and inserts 1 as the amount of clicks into a thing called click.

If the username already exists, I want it to add one to the existing click value. I'm trying to make it case insensitive. However, it doesn't seem to work!

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE username='$ytusernamecheck'");

  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

  if ($numrows < 0)  
  {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO clicks (username, clicks)
                                      VALUES ('$ytusernamecheck', 1)");
      echo $numrows;

  }
  else{}
```

Comment: What exactly _"does not work"_? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should probably do is create a unique index on `username` and instead use [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html);

```sql
-- first do: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_clicks ON clicks(username);

INSERT INTO clicks VALUES ('username', 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clicks = clicks + 1;
```

It will do the insert/update in one operation without an extra query to the database.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8904/1).

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in this line:

```
if ($numrows = '')
```

1. You are assigning (`=`), not comparing values (`==` or `===`).
2. `mysql_num_rows()` returns an integer, not an empty string.

Your final result should look like this:

```
if ($numrows === 0)
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: sorry i may be blind. where does he have if ($numrows='')

Comment: They editted their post after I posted my answer. It's annoying when they do that.

Comment: anyone that is willing to say that an edit was made concerning a certain verbeage when it wasn't gets an upvote from me! so +1 as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a unique key on the username field and use this instead

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO clicks (username, clicks) VALUES ('$ytusernamecheck', 1) 
on duplicate key update clicks=clicks+1");
```

Only 1 SQL statement to execute that way